# objective-c string manipulation

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a string
"AA - The Title of the Person"

How can I get the part before the '-'?

The output should be "AA"

Also if the input doesn't have a '-' then output should be nil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSInteger hyphenStart = [theString rangeOfString:@" - "].location;
if(hyphenStart == NSNotFound)
    return nil;
return [theString substringToIndex:hyphenStart];
```

Comment: will this give me "AA " or just "AA"?

Comment: The NSString class docs are quite good, and the class has a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class documentation.